# Elasticache using spring aws cloud

Tags: memcached, spring-cloud, amazon-elasticache, spring-cloud-aws

I am looking to implement ElastiCache(using memcached) for my spring application. From [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_configuring_caching_using_java_configuration) I can see that this can be done using spring cloud aws, but I could not find proper steps for doing this anywhere. Can anyone please provide some example implementation or tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Simple Spring Memcached (SSM)](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached) project. It provides integration with [AWS Elasticache](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached/tree/master/aws-elasticache-provider) through custom annotations or Spring Cache Abstraction.